# Issue with State when using Firebase snapshot onChange in React Native tab screen

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out why my Tasks state doesn't accumulate on Firebase Snapshop change. From some reason, it keeps thinking I have only one item in State.
From my thinking perspective, it should add to the existing state on load plus listen to changes for upcoming events.

Is any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
const TasksScreen = ( {navigation} ) => {
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();
    const [ tasks, setTasks ] = useState( [] );
    const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState( true );

    const appendTask = ( data ) => {
        const newTasks = [ ...tasks ];
        newTasks.push( data );
        setTasks( newTasks );
    }

    const loadAllDocuments = () => {
        unsubscribeFromFirebase = Firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection( 'tasks' )
            .onSnapshot(
                ( snapshot ) => {
                    snapshot.docChanges().forEach( ( change ) => {
                        if (change.type === 'added') {
                            appendTask( change.doc.data() );
                        }
                        if (change.type === 'modified') {
                        }
                        if (change.type === 'removed') {
                        }
                    } );
                    setIsLoading( false );
                }
            );
    }

    React.useEffect( () => {
        if (isFocused) {
            loadAllDocuments();
        }

        return () => {
            setTasks( [] );
            unsubscribeFromFirebase();
        }
    }, [ isFocused ] );


    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
                <Text key={`key-${0}`} style={styles.item}>=={tasks.length}=====</Text>
                {
                    tasks.map( ( task, index ) => {
                        return (
                            <Text key={`key-${index}`} style={styles.item}>{task.tip}</Text>
                        )
                    } )
                }
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};
```